# wrapping the data while exporting xls using data tables

Tags: excel, laravel, datatables

I am exporting the data as XLS file in data-tables. The column with around 200 words stores the data in xls sheet keeping the height constant, which makes it look weird. Can I wrap the text in exported file?

The way I declare data-table.

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
        var table =  $('#dataTable').DataTable( {
            "aaSorting": [],
            "pageLength": <?= \App\Utilities\Constants::REPORT_RECORDS_PER_PAGE?>,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible'
                    }
                },
                'colvis'
            ]
        } );

    } );
```

Here is screenshot of the report:
[image]

and here you go with the xls output:

[image]

Comment: I'm presuming that you are exporting data into an existing xls file? If so, can you not format the sheet and then try to export the data? I haven't tried this so I'm not convinced it would work

Comment: export the files a new sheet. No adding into the existing one @Zac